# WordPress index archives not working (Prev / Next)

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a strange issue whereby my blog index archives pages (Previous Link) isn't working and is going to a 404 page.

I have a page set as the site's Index, and the News (Blog) section is located at a seperate page called 'news'. Archive pagination works fine for category archives, it just appears to be the index.php loop that is not allowing the archives pagination to work for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated, here's my code from my theme's index.php file that dips into the loop for posts:

```
<?php       

                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array(
                    // 'cat' => -13, // Exclude Guide To's
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
                    );

                $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );  
                if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                    $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                <? }  } 

            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have set a static front page. In that case

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

is wrong. `paged` is used for any page, except a static front page. Static front pages uses `page`. So you should change the above mentioned line to

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

**EDIT**

Your [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) should also be adjusted for custom queries. You have to set the `$max_pages` parameter

```
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $latest_posts->max_num_pages );
```

**EDIT 2**

Seems like your rewrite rules seems to be the problem. Add the following to your functions.php and reload your index page a few times.

```
function bt_flush_rewrite_rules() {
     flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE** You should delete this function immediately after reloading your index page a few times. [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) are a really expensive operation that is quite tough on resources, so it should **ONLY** be used if really really necessary

Comment: Hi Pieter, yes you do understand correctly, I have a static front page, however the error I'm getting is on my separately nominated 'posts' page. I'm not pulling out any posts at all on my static page for the homepage. I've tried the adjustment to page, but unfortunately, the prev/next buttons still 404.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I've added this to the next/prev links however the /page/2 URL still 404's. If you have any other ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I remove custom Permalinks, and use default it seems to work just fine, might be something to do with htaccess?